# inserted pictures in wrong sheet (last in place first) PHPEXCEL

Tags: php, phpexcel

I create a xlsx file :

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i);
```

I put a picture into a cell with this code :

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
           $objDrawing->setName('logo PHARMA');
           $objDrawing->setDescription('logo PHARMA');
           $objDrawing->setPath('../../images/pharma.png');
           $objDrawing->setHeight(136);
           $objDrawing->setCoordinates('B1');
           $objDrawing->setOffsetX(-10);
           $objDrawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
```

Inside the first sheet, I have no picture, but in the last sheet (where I have no informaiton, I do not need this last sheet), I have pictures.

I have a problem a interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation when you create a new sheet, "By default, this will be created as a new last sheet" so the following line will insert a new sheet at the end.

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
```

A possible solution I think would be to change the last line to this

```
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```